# Search and replace operation

Tags: python, replace

I have a list which has URL values like:

```
http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5149/5684108566_aed8b9b52d_s.jpg
```

How can I change the `_s` in the end to `_m` for all occurrences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
str = "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5149/5684108566_aed8b9b52d_s.jpg"
str = str.replace("_s","_m")
```

If you want to be sure that only the las part is changed and you know all are `.jpg` files you can use:

```
str = "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5149/5684108566_aed8b9b52d_s.jpg"
str = str.replace("_s.jpg","_m.jpg")
```

To give some more context and avoid changes on the middle of the url.

Comment: +1 for more context checking. A `.rreplace` method could be useful here.

Answer (score 4):

Or if you want to be able to do this on **any file extension** and make sure nothing in the string is altered except for the last part.

```
import re

str = "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5149/5684108566_aed8b9b52d_s.jpg"
re.sub("(.*)_s(\.[a-z0-9]{1,4})$", r"\1_m\2", str)
str = "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5149/5684108566_aed8b9b52d_s.png"
re.sub("(.*)_s(\.[a-z0-9]{1,4})$", r"\1_m\2", str)
str = "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5149/5684108566_aed8b9b52d_s.gif"
re.sub("(.*)_s(\.[a-z0-9]{1,4})$", r"\1_m\2", str)
str = "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5149/5684108566_aed8b9b52d_s.zip"
re.sub("(.*)_s(\.[a-z0-9]{1,4})$", r"\1_m\2", str)
```

Output:

```
>>> str = "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5149/5684108566_aed8b9b52d_s.jpg"
>>> re.sub("(.*)_s(\.[a-z0-9]{1,4})$", r"\1_m\2", str)
'http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5149/5684108566_aed8b9b52d_m.jpg'

>>> str = "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5149/5684108566_aed8b9b52d_s.png"
>>> re.sub("(.*)_s(\.[a-z0-9]{1,4})$", r"\1_m\2", str)
'http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5149/5684108566_aed8b9b52d_m.png'

>>> str = "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5149/5684108566_aed8b9b52d_s.gif"
>>> re.sub("(.*)_s(\.[a-z0-9]{1,4})$", r"\1_m\2", str)
'http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5149/5684108566_aed8b9b52d_m.gif'

>>> str = "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5149/5684108566_aed8b9b52d_s.zip"
>>> re.sub("(.*)_s(\.[a-z0-9]{1,4})$", r"\1_m\2", str)
'http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5149/5684108566_aed8b9b52d_m.zip'
```